# Bootstrap datepicker multiple date background change

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap datepicker like this.

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/swapnilmotewar/tuG6C/609/`
```

Is there anyway i can highlight(with diff background) more than one previous dates ? I dont want to select,just wanted to highlight (it is just work as an indicator to the user that those are the potential dates they are actually looking for.).

If not with bootstrap, is it possible with jquery or any other library?

Comment: Are you looking for a tooltip functionality ?

Comment: possible answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514772/highlight-certain-dates-on-bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: thanks GrafiCode, i'll checkout the thread.. it looks like similar issue..