# How to use multiple beforeshowday functions django?

Tags: javascript

I wish to give specific color to specific dates in datepicker and also disable the weekend days. Please help me out. Thank You!

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var LiveDates = {};
    LiveDates[new Date('07/18/2019')] = new Date('07/18/2019');

    $('.datepicker1').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
        minDate: new Date({{a}},{{b}},{{c}}),
        maxDate: new Date({{d}},{{e}},{{f}}),
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var Highlight = LiveDates[date];
            if (Highlight) {
                return [true, "live", 'Tooltip text'];
            }
            else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22514772/highlight-certain-dates-on-bootstrap-datepicker

Comment: sorry i am using jquery datepicker not bootstrap datepicker